# XML schema restriction such that value of a child element can be true only for one parent sibling at any given point of time

Tags: xml, xsd

I know I have not done a good job in defining the title, not sure how to articulate my question. Let me try to explain it here.

I have `XML` like this:

```
<School>
 <Teacher>
  <Student>
    <Name>Todd</Name>
    <Phone>
     <Number>7324567890</Number>
     <PrefPhone>1</PrefPhone>
    </Phone>
    <Phone>
     <Number>98765467890</Number>
     <PrefPhone>0</PrefPhone>
    </Phone>
    <Phone>
     <Number>77765467890</Number>
     <PrefPhone>0</PrefPhone>
    </Phone>
  </Student>
 </Teacher>
</School>
```

Now my question: How to define schema restriction that only one `<Phone>` per `<Student>` has `<PrefPhone>` set to `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you're using XML Schema 1.1**, you can [specify co-occurrence constraints](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xml11pt2/) via XPath 2.0.  I.e. something like this (untested):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="1.1">
  <xs:element name="Student">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Name"/>
        <xs:element name="Phone" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="PhoneType"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="count('./Phone/PrefPhone[. = 1]') le 1"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**If you're using XML Schema 1.0**, you cannot express such constraints.  However, you might define a distinct `PreferedPhone` element such that there's only one per `Student` as a work-around:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="1.0">
  <xs:element name="Student">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Name"/>
        <xs:element name="PreferedPhone" maxOccurs="1" type="PhoneType"/>
        <xs:element name="Phone" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="PhoneType"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please expand your answer on how would you define `PrefPhone` element in `1.0`

Comment: Sure, I added sketches of both approaches.

Comment: Oh you meant define `PrefPhone` as element of `Student` instead of `Phone`... right?

Comment: Right, so instead of making `PrefPhone` a flag on `Phone`, create a distinguished type of phone called `PreferedPhone` of which there can only be one (`maxOccurs="1"`) per `Student`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to ensure that there is exactly one (or at most one) preferred phone is to make two distinct elements for telephone numbers:  exactly (or at most) one preferred phone number, and any number of other phone numbers.  The two elements can have the same type, since both are phone numbers.

An even simpler solution is to say that the preferred number is the first phone number given in the document instance.